# ZigBee stack - the communication between different layers

Tags: zigbee

In ZigBee stack, different layers communicate through SAP ( Service Access Point )

For example, APS communicates with NWK through NDLE-SAP.

However, are there any document, website or books explain these SAPS in detail ?

Such as are they bi-directional ? and some other knowledge in these SAPs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the official ZigBee specs here: http://www.zigbee.org/zigbee-for-developers/network-specifications/zigbeepro/#learnmore
They are free to download after the registration.